# AngularJs: Is it possible to pass value to controller or directive from outside?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm initialising the controller and directive inside a function that is called somewhere else. So is it possible to send the param value of the function to controller/directive. Here is my code.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

var init = function initialize(id) {
    myModule.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        // Here I want to use parameter value id
    }]);

    myModule.directive('myDirective', function () {
        var Directive = {};
        Directive.template = 'Hello World!';
        Directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Here I want to use parameter value id
        }

        return Directive;
    });

    $('body').attr('ng-controller', 'myController');
    angular.bootstrap($('body'), ['myModule']);
}
```

Here, I'm able to successfully call init from outside but I'm not able to get the value of id in either controller or directive.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have structured your code, you don't have to pass the id explicitly. The controller is defined inside a closure that has access to the id. This means you can just use the id as if it was passed as a parameter to the controller or directive.

I recommend that you read this article for details: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp